# Pandas: removing everything in a column after first value above threshold

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm interested in the first time a random process crosses a threshold. I am storing the results from observing the process in a dataframe, and have plotted how many times several realisations of that process cross 0.9 after I observe it a the end of 14 rounds.

[image]

This image was created with this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fin = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.uniform(size=(100, 13))).T
pos = (fin>0.9).astype(float) 
ax=fin.loc[:, pos.loc[12, :] != 1.0].plot(figsize=(12, 6), color='silver', legend=False)
fin.loc[:, pos.loc[12, :] == 1.0].plot(figsize=(12, 6), color='indianred', legend=False, ax=ax)
```

where `fin` contained the random numbers, and `pos` was `1` every time that process crossed `0.9`.

I would like to now plot the *first* time the process in `fin` crosses `0.9` for each realisation (columns represent realisations, rows represent observation times)

I can find the first occurence of a value above `0.9` with `idxmax()` but I'm stumped about how to remove everything in the dataframe after that in each column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.uniform(size=(100, 10)))
maxes = df.idxmax()
```

It's just that I'm having real difficulty thinking through this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use

```py
df = df[df.index < maxes[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can use a boolean matrix with cumprod:

```
df.where((df < .9).cumprod().astype(bool)).plot()
```

Output:

[image]